# Scale groups of features before clustering

Tags: clustering, data-transformation

I would like to cluster some data, with groups of features:

For example:

```
age |  size  | face_feature_1 | face_feature_2 | face_feature_3 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
 48 |   180   |      0.4       |       0.7      |        0.8     |  
 45 |   174   |      0.1       |       0.3      |        0.9     |  
 23 |   188   |      0.8       |       0.6      |        0.3     |
```

If I scale and then compute a distance matrix, overall face features would count as 3/5 in my clustering, age for 1/5 and size for 1/5.

I would like to count all face features with same weight as age or size.

Is there any easy data transformation that achieves such work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply the face features with 1/3.

Then they only have 1/3 of the original weight.

Comment: I understand this weight correction. Though, when could I apply a scaling step in this process? Should I scale before multiplying by 1/3 these features?

Comment: Do it last. You could even do it within the distance function only.